# Поиск по подстроке Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть таблица c полем description. Как мне сделать поиск в таблице по этому полю так, чтоб выводились не только записи в которых description полностью совпадает с запросом поиска, но и записей у который запрос является подстрокой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через критерию можно, если их используешь

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("description", "%"+description+"%"));
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
return criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from SomeEntity where description like :description");
query.setParameter("description", "%" + description + "%")
List<SomeEntity> entities = query.list()
```